# How to get all the descendants of this array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the `voornamen` and the `lidnummers` of all the users, I added them to firebase database I need a `<select>` list to select the user you want to play with, this is what I tried:

```
//this is my database store where I get the users
const gebruikersref = firebase.database().ref('Gebruikers/')
        self = this
        gebruikersref.once('value', function(snapshot){
            //inside Gebruikers where all users are stored
            var voornamen = ''
            var lidnummers = ''
            var childlength = snapshot.numChildren()

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                //everything that is stored inside the user
                const data = childSnapshot.exportVal();
                self.voornamen = data.Voornaam
                self.lidnummers = data.Lidnummer
            });
            //loop through the length of gebruikers and set medespelers
            for(let i=0; i<childlength;i++) {
                self.medespelers = self.voornamen + " - " + self.lidnummers;
            }

        });
```

then in `data()` I return `medespelers: ''` and this is my html:

```
<select class="banen rounded">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in medespelers" :key="index">{{ medespelers }}</option>
</select>
```

My problem is that it only returns the last user because the foreach loop runs first sets all the users in `lidnummers and voornamen` and when the last user is set the for loop runs which means that it only calls the last user X the childitems in gebruikers. I also tried nesting the for loop in the foreach loop but that won't work because it will return all users X the users in gebruikers. Does anyone know how I fix my problem and just get all users X 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your second loop is unnecessary.  Try this:

```js
const medespelers = []; // new empty array 

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
   //everything that is stored inside the user
   const data = childSnapshot.exportVal();
   self.voornamen = data.Voornaam
   self.lidnummers = data.Lidnummer
   medespelers.push(self.voornamen + " - " + self.lidnummers); // adding to the array
});

self.medespelers = medespelers; // setting your array to the data variable
```

You should also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as callbacks to avoid the need for the `self` convention.